# React Native iOS Share Sheet Apps Missing Instagram

Tags: ios, react-native, instagram

I've downloaded instagram and tiktok to test on a new phone, but they don't show up in the share sheet.

Is it because you can't share to instagram this way? I'm doing it like this:

```
import {Share} from 'react-native';
...
  Share.share({
    message: 'hello world',
    title: 'Content',
    url: 'https://instagram.com',
  });
```

Does sharing to instagram not work with React Native share sheet? Or am I doing it wrong?

If this doesn't work I will try linking.

Edit:
I tried adding an image

```
  Share.share({
    message: 'hello world',
    title: 'Content',
    url: content.product.image,
    // image url

  });
```

still doesn't show